# Debian login loop, can't login with correct password

Tags: debian, login, lightdm

I've updated my repositories on synabtics the upgraded firefox to newer version, when I open it it crashes, while this I was having my hard drive plugged .. so I tried to reboot to fix Firefox crash ..
From that point I can't login, tried many solutions as I can. Additional information could help you solving my problem that my computer reading the unplugged hard drive with its two partions .. tried to unmount it but with no success.

Comment: I'm a little confused as to what you mean by 'plugged/unplugged' hard drive. So, your system boots up to the login window, but your password doesn't work? Does it seem similar to [this issue](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop) at Ask Ubuntu?

Comment: Currently there is no hard drive attached to my computer, however when writing ls command it show the tow partitions from the drive

Comment: I've tried the solution in the mentioned issue but with no success

Comment: Can you login in tty ?

Answer (score 0):

Almost same as Ubuntu login loop

> (Ctrl-Alt-F1)

enter comand line

> sudo su

login as root and

> ls -a

to see files then delete .Xauthority .Xauthority-c .Xauthority-l 
.xsession-errors .xsession-errors.old
files

> rm -r .Xauthority .Xauthority-c .Xauthority-l  .xsession-errors .xsession-errors.old

then restart

Comment: that's a solid answer to my issue! thanks @Baganaakh

Answer (score 0):

For me, the problem was only for one particular user and was related to Chrome Remote Desktop. The solution was:

```
sudo apt purge chrome-remote-desktop
```

See [17.04 update login loop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/949456/17-04-update-login-loop).